# Retornar un Arreglo Dinámico c++

Tags: c++, array, manejo-de-memoria

Necesito devolver un array dinámico como en este caso en el mismo método para poder utilizarlo de nuevo como parámetro en otro método de la clase:

```
class Grupo
{public:

    Grupo(){};
    Alumno* RegistAlum();

};

Alumno *Grupo::RegistAlum()
{

    Alumno *A[]={new Alumno("Juan", 19, 123), new Alumno("Lupita", 18, 124), new Alumno("Carlos", 19, 121)};
     return A; }
```

Al retornar `A` me sale error. He utilizado varias maneras pero me sigue  marcando error.

Comment: provee un [mcve]

Comment: ¿ Que error te muestra ? ¿ Que has intentado ? La idea del sitio **no es ser tu depurador personal**. Es aunar conocimientos **que puedan serles útiles a otros** que se encuentren en tu misma situación y con tu mismo problema. Y para ello, **hay que ser claro**; los detalles **son importantes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás devolviendo un puntero a `Alumno` cuando estás creando una formación<sup>1</sup> de punteros a `Alumno`:

```
   Alumno *Grupo::RegistAlum()
// ~~~~~~~~ <--- Puntero a alumno
{

    Alumno *A[] =
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- Formacion de punteros a alumno
    {
        new Alumno("Juan", 19, 123),
        new Alumno("Lupita", 18, 124),
        new Alumno("Carlos", 19, 121)
    };

    return A;
}
```

Para solucionar este problema o cambias el retorno:

```
Alumno **Grupo::RegistAlum()
```

O cambias la formación<sup>1</sup>:

```
Alumno *A = new Alumno[3]
{
    Alumno("Juan", 19, 123),
    Alumno("Lupita", 18, 124),
    Alumno("Carlos", 19, 121)
};
```

Has de tener en cuenta que en tu código original estás devolviendo una variable local, la cuál se pierde cuando finaliza la llamada al método; para devolver el valor sin que se pierda, debes reservar memoria como se ve en el código anterior. Pero la mejor solución sería utilizar un contenedor, como por ejemplo `std::vector<Alumno>`:

```
std::vector<Alumno> Grupo::RegistAlum()
{
    return
    {
        Alumno("Juan", 19, 123),
        Alumno("Lupita", 18, 124),
        Alumno("Carlos", 19, 121)
    };
}
```

---

También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Me ha servido demasiado Amigo! Gracias y disculpen si no pude explicarme de la mejor manera!

Comment: Tendrán un enlace que me pueda ayudar a saber más sobre memoria dinámica en arreglos?

Comment: @JohnH.Gómez una duda sobre "memória dinámica en arreglos" es muy amplia, tendrás que aclarar la duda y valorar si hacer una pregunta al respecto. Si quieres podemos ayudarte a aclarar dudas o a redactar una pregunta sobre arreglos si te pasas por [el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).